# How to highlight (draw a semi-transparent straight line) with Gimp without having the starting point visible?

Tags: gimp

I'd like to highlight parts of a screen capture with semi-transparent straight lines with Gimp. I know how to draw straight lines (click on a point, press and hold the shift key, and if needed the Ctrl key with it and click to the end of the spotted zone). But with an opacity level lesser than 100%, the starting point is double-higlighted and this is unpleasant. See pic below :
[image]

Thus, how to set starting point without any pen stroke ? I've tried to click then undo, but this also removes the localization of the stroke... All you can do is continuous-yet-broken line.

Many thanks in advance & regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had this problem recently and ended up using the Path tool:

- draw the path
- hit 'Stroke Path' in the tool options
- hit 'Stroke with a paint tool' in the 'Choose Stroke Style' option box
- pick Paintbrush (or whatever) as the paint tool to get the right opacity/color/etc

[image: screenshot of the correct tool options for this]

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously no one has an answer. Here is the way I got around the difficulty :

- make a rectangular selection of the zone you want to highlight ;
- fill this area with the color you want and the adequate opacity level.

This does not gave me the smoothness I wanted do get in the corners, but it dit the trick well enough...